# How do I get the output of this JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

How do I get the output of this JavaScript function?

```
function getViewport() {
   return {
      width: document.documentElement.clientWidth;
      height: document.documentElement.clientHeight;
   };
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "how do I get the output"? Can you clarify exactly *what part of that* you're confused about?

Comment: @AlexisKing is `getViewport.width` enough if the functions name was getViewport?

Comment: Hey... So you call a function `getViewport` like this - `getViewport()` Now, in this function returns an object which has two fields `width` and `height`. So, `var obj = getViewport();`, `var width = obj.width; var height = obj.height;` or `var width = getViewport().width;`, `var height = getViewport().height;` will work.

Comment: Do not ask such questions on StackOverFlow. For future reference please read - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your function will return object , so you can take it like var obj=getViewport(); and then var width=obj.width;, var height=obj.height; like this

Answer (score 3):

It's an anonymous function, so you'd need to call it immediately and assign the results to a variable if you want to work with it.

```
var theOutput = function() {
   return {
      width: document.documentElement.clientWidth;
      height: document.documentElement.clientHeight;
   };
}();
```

After the edit, it is no longer anonymous, so to call it:

```
var theOutput = getViewport();
console.log('The width is: ' + theOutput.width);
```

Comment: accordind to ur code, is `theOutput.width` enough for getting the width, mate?

Comment: Yes, that should do it. Edited my answer for your edit.

Comment: rather than assignig the function to a variable, can i call it like `getViewport().width`

Comment: @iamabin: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: @FelixKling i always think that there are many ways to get something done in js. i always prefer using the most perfect way. that's why i'm asking sort of questions...

Comment: @iamabin: But you didn't ask what the preferred way is, you just asked whether it is *possible*. And that you can find out by yourself :) (there is no "perfect"/"preferred" way btw)